# Problem with PHP HTML-mail including multiple images

Tags: php, email

i'm writing a little mail plugin in php for user information and i want to integrate multiple images in base64 encoding, the problem is, that only the first image is integrated. Any solution? All paths are correct, and html is integrated successfull. If I exchange the order of the images integrated in code, the image displayed in Mail also changes, so both of them are available, but they're not displayed at the same time.

```
<?php

  $ImageLocation ="images/logo.gif";
  $ImageLocationRight ="images/right2.jpg";
  $ImgName = "logo.gif";
  $ImgNameRight = "right2.jpg";
  $MailFrom="Tool";
  $MailFromAdr="no_reply@xyz.com";
  $MailTo ="xyzr@xyz.com";
  $MailToSubject = "$subject";

  $CID = md5(uniqid (rand(), 1));

  $mime_boundary = "" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), 1));  


  $Header= "From:$MailFrom<$MailFromAdr>\n";
  $Header.= "X-mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(). "\n";  
  $Header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $Header.= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"; type=\"text/plain\"\n"; 

  $MailBody = "--".$mime_boundary."\n";
  $MailBody.= "Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=iso-8859-1$EOL";  
  $MailBody.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n";  
  $MailBody.= file_get_contents("../mail/mail.htm");
  $MailBody.= "\n\n";
  $MailBody.= "--".$mime_boundary."\n";  

  $MailBody= str_replace("images/logo.gif", "cid:$CID.$ImgName", $MailBody);
  $MailBody= str_replace("images/right2.jpg", "cid:$CID.$ImgNameRight", $MailBody);





  $fpr = fopen ($ImageLocationRight, "rb");
  $strr = fread ($fpr, filesize ($ImageLocationRight));
  $datar = chunk_split(base64_encode($strr));
  $content.= "Content-Type: image/jpg\n";
  $content.= "Content-ID: <$CID.$ImgNameRight>\n";
  $content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  $content.= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$ImgNameRight\"\n\n";
  fclose($fpr);

  $content.= $datar."\n";

  $MailBody.= $content;
  $MailBody.= "--".$mime_boundary."--\n";

  $fp = fopen ($ImageLocation, "rb");
  $str = fread ($fp, filesize ($ImageLocation));
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($str));
  $content = "";
  $content.= "Content-Type: image/gif\n";
  $content.= "Content-ID: <$CID.$ImgName>\n";
  $content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
  $content.= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$ImgName\"\n\n";  
  fclose($fp);


  $content.= $data."\n";

  $MailBody.= $content;
  $MailBody.= "--".$mime_boundary."--\n";

  echo $MailBody;

  mail($MailTo, $MailToSubject, $MailBody, $Header);
 ?>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, If you send a lot of mails you might want to use a preexisting mail library to do all the heavy lifting. I use swiftMail a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't found a solution for this, I ran into a similar problem and finally got what it is causing this!

Just after you attach your first image, just eliminate the closing dashes for the MIME boundary:

Instead of having this code:

```
$MailBody.= "--".$mime_boundary."--\n";
```

Try this instead:

```
$MailBody.= "--".$mime_boundary."\n";
```

This is only for all the images before the last one, you must keep the closing dashes in the very last image.

Answer (score 0):

hi you are not concating the images with you $mailbody string. your code should be like this

```
$MailBody .= str_replace("images/logo.gif", "cid:$CID.$ImgName", $MailBody);
 $MailBody .= str_replace("images/right2.jpg", "cid:$CID.$ImgNameRight", $MailBody);
```

Comment: I don't think that I'll have to do that, because str_replace only does replace my placeholders in HTML, and that's correct.